# How can I use the yum Python module to get a list of packages that will be downloaded before accepting the transaction?

Tags: python, yum

I am writing my first Yum plugin, which I hope to use to display some info about the packages to be downloaded on an update or an install. I have successfully gotten the plugin to run and have it all set up properly. **My problem is getting a list of packages that will be downloaded before the user accepts or cancels the transaction.**

There is a method available in a certain conduit, the one provided to `predownload_hook(conduit)` and `postdownload_hook(conduit)`, that can be called with `conduit.getDownloadPackages()` to do exactly what I want. However, both of these hooks are called after the user accepts or declines the transaction. According to the yum Python API docs, `getDownloadPackages()` is not available anywhere else.

I have asked about this in #yum on Freenode a couple of times but haven't gotten an answer. A solution or any help is greatly appreciated. Have a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the postresolve_hook(), and walk the transaction list. To see a fairly simple copy and paste example look at the changelog plugin (displays the rpm changelog for everything to be installed/upgraded in the transaction).

Comment: This was perfect! I knew the package list must be available where I wanted it. Thank you!